# Can two UML sequence diagram frames overlap?

Tags: uml

is it acceptable to overlap two frames in a uml sequence daigram?

For example two opt frames:

[image]

Comment: Interactions should form strict containments (every frame is owned by a single parent frame), and messages cannot cross frame boundaries -- so the first "dispatch" should be wrong too -- that's what gates are for

Comment: So I doubt this is valid UML, but to give you a precise technical answer I need a bit more specifications research...

Comment: That looks fine to me. Regarding crossing boundaries, take a look at gates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As long as it is useful, and understandable to others; that is, to anyone who will be reading the diagrams.

[UML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) is "general-purpose" and "*intended* to provide a standard way to visualize the design of a system." It is a **tool** that we can use.

UML is standardised but it is up-to you, and your organisation, as to how closely the documented standards are followed.

Answer (score 0):

It creates confusion. Is the first 'dispatch' message part of opt frame, or does happen before the option? For me, as a reader of your diagram, it's unclear. Frame overlapping could be avoided in either case.